# amazon route53 with beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nameservers

Its been almost 3 days but I still cannot get the my website working with route53.

This is my route53 settings

[image: route53]

the test.com and *test.com both have the same alias target
I have updated the nameservers in godaddy and have removed everything else.

[image]

nameservers in godaddy

[image]

Do I need to edit anything on the beanstalk server?

Comment: Do you actually own test.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have decreases the TTL in amazon. Its fixed right now